# Why is my last value overwritten the rest of my list?

Tags: python

I have this code

```
DATA = [
{"Value":0}
]

dicDATA = {"Value":0}

var = 0

#in some function...
print("Insert a value:")
var = int(input())

dicDATA["Value"] = var
DATA.append(dicDATA)

for i in DATA:
    print(i["Value"])
```

If i insert a value 2 ,I expect the output to be 2 and it's ok but if i insert another value 5 , I expect the output of:

```
2
5
```

But the actual output is:

```
5
5
```

The value gets overwritten

Comment: It's likely you're inserting the same variable - not just the same *value*, but the same *variable* - every time. When you change the value of that variable, it also changes for everything else that looks at it - because each index of the list is looking at the same thing, they all report seeing the same thing.

Comment: @GreenCloakGuy No, *variables* are not inserted into lists, *objects* are. The issue is that the same object (in this case a dictionary) is being added to the list multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

You're not making a copy of `dicData` every time you append it. So you're appending the same dictionary every time.

You should create a new dictionary each time you append.

```
print("Insert a value:")
var = int(input())

dicDATA = {"Value": var}
DATA.append(dicDATA)
```